# How to save the data that has same model but with different data in Django

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, django-forms

I'm working on a mini project which uses Django 1.8. The aim is to build a small billing app. So, I've created two models, Bill and Product, as follows.

```
#bill/models.py

class Bill(models.Model):
  date_of_issue = models.DateField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="N/A", null=True)
  address = models.CharField(max_length=150, default="N/A", null=True)
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "{} {}".format(self.input_name, self.date_of_issue)

class Product(models.Model):
  bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="N/A")
  quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
  total = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

By seeing the model, you can tell that my approach is to create Bill and Product tables and connect the Product to Bill via ForeignKey. Now, the thing is that a single bill will contain at least one product. If there are more than one product, how should I write my views in *views.py*. I'm a beginner in the Django development. If a Bill contains a single Product then I can write its view. But how can I store multiple Product which have different data and storing it in database.

**For Example**

The user will enter the name and address of the customer. Then the user will enter the details of products. Now I want to generate the Product modelform more than once (depends upon the number of products added by user). How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: Use a `formset`.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/

Comment: I suggest you look at the ERD for the Northwind database, I think it will help you visualize what you need. There are various versions but this is the original I think.
http://www.ariacom.com/images/Northwind%20ERD.png

Comment: formset, tutorials - all that will help. A few specific points on your models: 1 - your current setup is effectively order master + order detail. It doesn't allow for reusing product - i.e., each "product" is ONLY a line on an order - you may want to have Product be the actual products and LineItems or OrderDetail or something like that connect between Order & Product - basic design question depending on what you are trying to do; 2 - you have quantity & total but no unit price; 3 total (and unit price) in many places need decimals not integer but that depends on your local currency.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

**1)** multiple products can be bought at once (and thus be part of one bill) and

**2)** one product can be bought multiple at any time (and thus be part of many bills)

a simple foreign key is the wrong modelling attempt. Instead of a **m:1** relation you need a **m:n** relation - and thus a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField). With a ManyToManyField you can add multiple products to one bill or have mutiple products added to multiple bills. In django-admin it's useful (and I recommend it) to put ManyToManyFields as `filter_horizontal` which eases the use of this field.

Plus, django will automatically resolve your **m:n** relation with an additional third database table, so you don't need to take care of this.